# python append() and remove html tags

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, append

I need some help. My output seems wrong. How can I correctly append the values of dept, job_title, job_location. And there are html tags with the values of dept. how can I remove those tags.

my code

```
response = requests.get("http://hortonworks.com/careers/open-positions/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

jobs = []


div_main = soup.select("div#careers_list")


for div in div_main:
    dept = div.find_all("h4", class_="department_title")
    div_career = div. find_all("div", class_="career")
    title = []
    location = []
    for dv in div_career:
        job_title = dv.find("div", class_="title").get_text().strip()
        title.append(job_title)
        job_location = dv.find("div", class_="location").get_text().strip()
        location.append(job_location)

    job = {
        "job_location": location,
        "job_title": title,
        "job_dept": dept
    }
    jobs.append(job)
pprint(jobs)
```

It should look like

{'job_dept': Consulting,

'job_location':'Chicago, IL'

'job_title': Sr. Consultant - Central'

1 value for each variables.

Comment: please show the output you get...

Comment: the output will shows, job_dept: all depts, job _location: all location, job_title: all title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your html is sequential, not hierarchical, so you have to iterate through your job list and update department title as you go:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
from pprint import pprint
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20130331 Firefox/21.0'}
response = requests.get("http://hortonworks.com/careers/open-positions/", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

jobs = []


div_main = soup.select("div#careers_list")


for div in div_main:
    department_title = ""
    for element in div:
        if isinstance(element, Tag) and "class" in element.attrs:
            if "department_title" in element.attrs["class"]:
                department_title = element.get_text().strip()
            elif "career" in element.attrs["class"]:
                location = element.select("div.location")[0].get_text().strip()
                title = element.select("div.title")[0].get_text().strip()
                job = {
                    "job_location": location,
                    "job_title": title,
                    "job_dept": department_title
                }
                jobs.append(job)

pprint(jobs)
```

Comment: I have this error when I run this. if isinstance(element, Tag) and element.attrs.has_key("class"):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Comment: I've updated my answer so it would work with python3.

Comment: wow. Amazing. It works well. The output is correct.. I'm using a pycharm. the part    "job_dept": department_title. the department_title was highlighted. It said:     Name 'department_title' can be not defined

Comment: You have to initialize the `department_title` variable before using it. In our case it is fine, because we have a fixed sequence of html tags, but if there was no `div` tag with `department_title` class attribute before a `div` tag with `career` class attribute, there would have been an error. So, it would be better to set department_title variable to empty string before going into the second `for` loop.

Comment: okay great. Can you explain further about this line:
if isinstance(element, Tag) and "class" in element.attrs:
it's my first time to see that isinstance.

Comment: We are checking if `element` object is an instance of class `Tag`. You can find more information about this class here https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag.